# 2D Distorted Star Map for Pasting on Sphere Surface

Tags: star-maps

Are there printable 2D star maps that are distorted such that, when printed, they can be cut (along printed lines) to be applied to the outside of a sphere to represent the celestial sphere, as seen from the center of the substrate sphere?

Is there a term for this type of map?

If they don't exist, how can one be created?

Comment: What you're looking for is called a [star chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_chart) to make a [celestial sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_sphere).

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15639/what-projections-should-i-use-to-make-my-own-globe

Comment: Would two polar projections, one for each pole, suffice? It doesn't violate the Riemann Mapping Theorem since there's an irremovable discontinuity at the equator.

Comment: There's no way I know of to paste paper nicely on to a proper sphere, but there will be cut-outs you can tape together that look close to a sphere. I remember my old globe was indeed pieces of what looked like paper pasted to a glass sphere, but I have a hunch that was a fairly specialized paper and process developed for globe manufacture.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globe#Manufacture

Comment: I've found out that vertical segments that one would cut out to try to paste to a sphere are called [gores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gore_(segment)) and this is indeed how old globes were made. I know that the Python package [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) can generate locations of stars and the math to make a printable image superimposed on the gores is not hard. Is this a way you might want to proceed? Or are you looking for something you can just download and print?

Comment: Old videos about globe making: [1](https://youtu.be/4RWcWSN4HhI?t=72), [2](https://youtu.be/ldUnXrZYfY0?t=104), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1pcspwCRWc), [4](https://youtu.be/0qfJrCm5-q4?t=60) In the mean time, if you are bored, in-the-sky.org has a way to make a planisphere. https://in-the-sky.org/planisphere/index.php

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions and information! It has been immensely helpful.